# Send large files to GAE Blobstore via API (from S3)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, blobstore, filepicker.io

I'm trying to send large files (50MB-2GB) that I have stored in S3 using filepicker.io to the Google App Engine Blobstore (in Python). I would like this to happen without going through a form on the client browser as it defeats the project requirements (and often hangs with very large files).

I tried multiple solutions, including:

- trying to [load the file into GAE with urlfetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149315/how-do-i-integrate-filepicker-io-with-google-app-engine-blobstore) (but [GAE has a 32MB limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898736/upload-file-bigger-than-40mb-to-google-app-engine/6899157#6899157) for requests/responses)
- constructing a multi-part form in python and sending it to `blobstore.create_upload_url()` (can't transfer the file via url, and can't load it in the script because of the 32MB limit)
- using [boto to read the file straight into the blobstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948391/is-is-possible-to-read-a-file-from-s3-in-google-app-engine-using-boto) (connection times out and logs show `encountered HTTPException exception` from boto that triggers `CancelledError: The API call logservice.Flush() was explicitly cancelled.` from GAE that crashes the process.

I am struggling to find a working solution. Any hints on how I could perform this transfer, or how to pass the file from s3 as a form attachment without loading it in python first (ie. just specifying its url) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: use the http libraries, not a full answer but check it out

Comment: @peterretief you mean something like [python requests](http://www.python-requests.org/)?

Comment: I posted a question related to this suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973204/using-python-requests-to-bridge-a-file-without-loading-into-memory)

Answer (score 1):

The BlobstoreUploadHandler isn't constrained by a 32MB limit: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers.  However, I'm not sure how this might fit into your app.  If you can post the file to an endpoint handled by a BlobstoreUploadHandler, then you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks Robert, I have a BlobstoreUploadHandler already. 
My problem is how to send it the very large file that I have stored on S3 - I can't find a way to attach it to a POST request without loading it elsewhere in GAE first (which will cross the 32MB limit). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: There are those backend processors that don't have any limitations at all. Have you looked into those?

It is an interesting problem. I suppose you can't just leave the files in S3.  If you are letting the user interact with the app through the browser then you can use the html5 File api: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files to load the file into the browser (what happens when you load a 2GB file though).
Otherwise, you'll have to run a process outside the app engine to do all this.