# Using Python Requests to 'bridge' a file without loading into memory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'd like to use the [Python Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/) library to GET a file from a url and use it as a mulitpart encoded file in a post request. The catch is that the file could be very large (50MB-2GB) and I don't want to load it in memory. (Context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970514/send-large-files-to-gae-blobstore-via-api-from-s3).)

Following examples in the docs ([multipart](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), [stream down](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) and [stream up](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads)) I cooked up something like this:

```
    with requests.get(big_file_url, stream=True) as f:
        requests.post(upload_url, files={'file': ('filename', f.content)})
```

but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. It is in fact throwing this error - redacted from traceback:

```
    with requests.get(big_file_url, stream=True) as f:
    AttributeError: __exit__
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: replace the `with ... as f:` statement with `f = ...` and the `f.content` with `f` because `with` needs `__enter__` and `__exit__` and the docs tell me you can pass the file directly

Comment: @User thanks for the tip, but I get this error: `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'` - I assume this means that my code expects the file and not the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is an issue about that on Kenneth Reitz's GitHub [repo](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/295).
I had the same problem (although I'm just uploading a local file), and I added a wrapper class that is a list of streams corresponding to the different parts of the requests, with a read() attribute that iterates through the list and reads each part, and also gets necessary values for the headers (boundary and content-length) :

```
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from mimetools import choose_boundary
from requests.packages.urllib3.filepost import iter_fields, get_content_type
from io import BytesIO
import codecs

writer = codecs.lookup('utf-8')[3]

class MultipartUploadWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, files):
        """
        Initializer

        :param files:
            A dictionary of files to upload, of the form {'file': ('filename', <file object>)}
        :type network_down_callback:
            Dict
        """
        super(MultipartUploadWrapper, self).__init__()
        self._cursor = 0
        self._body_parts = None
        self.content_type_header = None
        self.content_length_header = None
        self.create_request_parts(files)

    def create_request_parts(self, files):
        request_list = []
        boundary = choose_boundary()
        content_length = 0

        boundary_string = b'--%s\r\n' % (boundary)
        for fieldname, value in iter_fields(files):
            content_length += len(boundary_string)

            if isinstance(value, tuple):
                filename, data = value
                content_disposition_string = (('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; ''filename="%s"\r\n' % (fieldname, filename))
                                            + ('Content-Type: %s\r\n\r\n' % (get_content_type(filename))))

            else:
                data = value
                content_disposition_string =  (('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"\r\n' % (fieldname))
                                            + 'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n')
            request_list.append(BytesIO(str(boundary_string + content_disposition_string)))
            content_length += len(content_disposition_string)
            if hasattr(data, 'read'):
                data_stream = data
            else:
                data_stream = BytesIO(str(data))

            data_stream.seek(0,2)
            data_size = data_stream.tell()
            data_stream.seek(0)

            request_list.append(data_stream)
            content_length += data_size

            end_string = b'\r\n'
            request_list.append(BytesIO(end_string))
            content_length += len(end_string)

        request_list.append(BytesIO(b'--%s--\r\n' % (boundary)))
        content_length += len(boundary_string)

        # There's a bug in httplib.py that generates a UnicodeDecodeError on binary uploads if
        # there are *any* unicode strings passed into headers as part of the requests call.
        # For this reason all strings are explicitly converted to non-unicode at this point.
        self.content_type_header = {b'Content-Type': b'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % boundary}
        self.content_length_header = {b'Content-Length': str(content_length)}
        self._body_parts = request_list

    def read(self, chunk_size=0):
        remaining_to_read = chunk_size
        output_array = []
        while remaining_to_read > 0:
            body_part = self._body_parts[self._cursor]
            current_piece = body_part.read(remaining_to_read)
            length_read = len(current_piece)
            output_array.append(current_piece)
            if length_read < remaining_to_read:
                # we finished this piece but haven't read enough, moving on to the next one
                remaining_to_read -= length_read
                if self._cursor == len(self._body_parts) - 1:
                    break
                else:
                    self._cursor += 1
            else:
                break
        return b''.join(output_array)
```

So instead of passing a 'files' keyword arg, you pass this object as  'data' attribute to your Request.request object

### Edit

I've cleaned up the code

Comment: Note: the response object returned by `requests.get()` has no `.seek()` method; the length could be calculated using GET headers in this case.

Comment: thanks for this - I ended up using a completely different approach, but this would've probably done the trick!

Comment: Thanks ! I'm curious to know more about your approach, though.

Answer (score 5):

As other answers have pointed out already: [`requests` doesn't support POSTing multipart-encoded files without loading them into memory](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/295).

To upload a large file without loading it into memory using multipart/form-data, you could use [`poster`](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

from poster.encode import multipart_encode # $ pip install poster
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers

register_openers() # install openers globally

def report_progress(param, current, total):
    sys.stderr.write("\r%03d%% of %d" % (int(1e2*current/total + .5), total))

url = 'http://example.com/path/'
params = {'file': open(sys.argv[1], "rb"), 'name': 'upload test'}
response = urlopen(Request(url, *multipart_encode(params, cb=report_progress)))
print response.read()
```

It can be adapted to allow a GET response object instead of a local file:

```
import posixpath
import sys
from urllib import unquote
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from urlparse import urlsplit

from poster.encode import MultipartParam, multipart_encode # pip install poster
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers

register_openers() # install openers globally

class MultipartParamNoReset(MultipartParam):
    def reset(self):
        pass # do nothing (to allow self.fileobj without seek() method)

get_url = 'http://example.com/bigfile'
post_url = 'http://example.com/path/'

get_response = urlopen(get_url)
param = MultipartParamNoReset(
    name='file',
    filename=posixpath.basename(unquote(urlsplit(get_url).path)), #XXX \ bslash
    filetype=get_response.headers['Content-Type'],
    filesize=int(get_response.headers['Content-Length']),
    fileobj=get_response)

params = [('name', 'upload test'), param]
datagen, headers = multipart_encode(params, cb=report_progress)
post_response = urlopen(Request(post_url, datagen, headers))
print post_response.read()
```

This solution requires a valid `Content-Length` header (known file size) in the GET response. If the file size is unknown then the chunked transfer encoding could be used to upload the multipart/form-data content. A similar solution could be implemented using `urllib3.filepost` that is shipped with `requests` library e.g., based on [@AdrienF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16221027/4279) without using `poster`.

Comment: I'd read about poster in my research, but didn't look deep enough - thought it had the same limitations as requests - my bad. This is a good solution, but I accepted @AdrienF 's as I was actually planning on using requests exclusively. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not turn anything you please into a context manager in python. It requires very specific attributes to be one. With your current code you can do the following:

```
response = requests.get(big_file_url, stream=True)

post_response = requests.post(upload_url, files={'file': ('filename', response.iter_content())})
```

Using `iter_content` will ensure that your file is never in memory. The iterator will be used, otherwise by using the `content` attribute the file **will** be loaded into memory.

**Edit** The only way to reasonably do this is to use [chunk-encoded uploads](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests), e.g.,

```
post_response = requests.post(upload_url, data=response.iter_content())
```

If you absolutely need to do multipart/form-data encoding then you will have to create an abstraction layer that will take the generator in the constructor, and the `Content-Length` header from `response` (to provide an answer for `len(file)`) that will have a read attribute that will read from the generator. The issue again is that I'm pretty sure the entire thing will be read into memory before it will be uploaded.

**Edit #2**

You might be able to make a generator of your own that produces the `multipart/form-data` encoded data yourself. You could pass that in the same way as you would chunk-encoded-requests but you'd have to make sure you set your own `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers. I don't have time to sketch an example but it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: iter_chunks throws an exception - did you mean iter_content?

with the latter I get an error similar to what I mentioned in the comments above: `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()` in the call to `write`

Comment: I'm going to update the answer because I forgot something, sorry. (In short you can not know the content length of that big file (I'm guessing) so you need to use chunked encoding to upload it.)

Comment: I can see why this would work, thanks. 
Unfortunately I do actually need the `multipart/form-data` as I need to send it to the GAE blobstore handler, as you can see in the linked context question.

Comment: Sorry. I hadn't seen the context question. I do have a different idea now though. :)

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can just the raw object

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: raw = requests.get("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip", stream=True).raw

In [3]: raw.read(10)
Out[3]: '\xff\xda\x18\x9f@\x8d\x04\xa11_'

In [4]: raw.read(10)
Out[4]: 'l\x15b\x8blVO\xe7\x84\xd8'

In [5]: raw.read() # take forever...

In [6]: raw = requests.get("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip", stream=True).raw

In [7]: requests.post("http://www.amazon.com", {'file': ('thing.zip', raw, 'application/zip')}, stream=True)
Out[7]: <Response [200]>
```