# processing large cloud storage files in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm required to process large files, up to 2GB, in GAE (I'm using Python).
of course I'll be running the code on a backend, however since a local storage isn't available the data will need to be in memory.

is there a file descriptor like wrapper for boto or other cloud storage supported protocol?
or other recommended technique?

Thanks,
Shay

Comment: You can use boto to access S3. Check out the link here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948391/is-is-possible-to-read-a-file-from-s3-in-google-app-engine-using-boto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe interesting in ["Google Cloud Storage Python API Overview"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview). It works like a regular local file. I've used it on my project and didn't encountered any problems with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the mentioned "Files API" is deprecated.The official successor, GCS, does not behave like a local file as it lacks support for modifying/appending. Any updated solution?

Comment: @jsphpl, here is the updated link: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

Comment: thanks for the link. I don't know how to say it differently, so please read my initial comment again.

Comment: @jsphpl, here is the example how you can work with arbitrary size files with Google Cloud Storage with Python from Google App Engine. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted I use this approach for my app and it works. And it does work for appending. Did you try it? Did it work? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

The data file doesnt "need to be in memory" and if you try that you will run oom.
If you can process it sequentially open it as a filestream. Ive done that with blobstore, should be similar